# Export fluid simulation data INSIDE file

Tags: rendering, blend-files, file-format, network

I am planning to use a render farm (render.st) to render an animation containing a mantaflow fluid simulation. Blender stores fluid simulation data outside of the .blend file, which I am unable to upload.

The "Automatically pack all into .blend" feature doesn't seem to pack the fluid data, as my fluid data folder is a whopping 14.4GB while the .blend file after packing is only 14.4MB.

Is there a way I can send mantaflow fluid sim data to a renderfarm?

Comment: Does the farm not accept zipped folders or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that question is in our (RenderStreet's) knowledge base, search for 'baking'. This is a quote from the first section in the article:

3. For uploading there are 4 options:

Use our plug-in. The plug-in will collect automatically all baked caches and all project assets and will upload them to our servers. You can download the plug-in from the link in your RenderStreet account

Zip the entire folder and upload via the "add render job page". You'll receive an error message saying that we were not able to find the blend file in the archive. In the process, the archive will get unzipped and then you'll be able to find the uploaded folder at the bottom of the page, in the FTP files section.

Via Dropbox or another cloud storage account .

Via FTP .

Also, when having a question regarding our service, asking our support will get you an answer :)